# latex and pdftex hangs when compiling

Tags: pdftex, miktex

I just updated my MiKTeX and now nor latex, neither pdflatex not compiling my tex. Even if it contains only

```tex
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

No error messages are shown, no files are created. It just hangs.

Comment: difficult to tell what is going on. Do you use a special class? maybe you downloaded miktex basic only and there are packages missing? If you use TenicCenter as editor, make sure you have "install missing packgaes on the fly" set to "yes" and not "ask me first" in the miktex settings. did you try compiling from the command line?

Comment: @MartinH It worked well about a hour ago. Now it doesn't work even in the command line. The only output I have is "C:\Users\efpies>pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "D:\Dropbox\Publicuniversity\Diplom\report.tex"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (MiKTeX 2.9)"

Comment: Delete the temporary files like `aux` `toc` etc. (clean project). It is generally not a good idea to sync within drop box (afaik). I think I read something some time ago that this may cause file version problems due to the radiply changing file versions...This may not be true however, I never tested it myself.

Comment: @MartinH I already cleaned the project. I also created a dummy .tex file in another folder (not in DropBox) — it hangs.

Comment: A minimal document also needs to contain a document class and one letter in the document. So does the following work? `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}Hello\end{document}` (Save it with a file name you haven't used before)

Comment: @doncherry It hangs.

Comment: I just updated on my netbook (winxp) and it works fine. But as the binaries have been updated the formats must be regenerated. Miktex triggers the format generation when you use pdflatex the first time. Perhaps this fails and so pdflatex hangs. Try to build the format through miktex settings to check if there are errors.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer How can I do this? There are no option "build the format"

Comment: There is on the tab "General" a button "update Formats" which will update all formats and there is a tab "Formats" with a button "build" which you can click as soon as you have choosen a format from the list. It will build a specific format. Use this for the first test.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, there were errors while processing *TeX* entries, but I thought it's all ok (I remember I've seen this before). There were errors with *fmt* executable (or file, not sure). Now, when I totally removed it from PC, formats updating well.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Okay, here's error: `I can't find file dehypht-x-2009-06-19.tex`

Comment: If I got it right you solved the problem by reinstalling miktex. Only for the record for other users: It can be solved by removing the obsolete german patterns (german, ngerman, swissgerman) with `2009-06-19` in their name from the language list (miktex settings, probably user mode, tab languages).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on the comments to your question, I think you will have to completely remove Miktex and reinstall it.

Comment: No. Before doing something drastic one should always have at least a vage idea what is the problem. If e.g. it is due to some broken exotic language file reinstalling everything will not help but the problem can be easily solved  by removing the language from `language.dat`.

Comment: Reinstalling Miktex requires very little (manual) work and is surely worth trying rather early.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unfortunately, I haven't enough time: my graduate work should been completed a few days ago...

Comment: I just installed miktex on a new PC and it took about 2 hours until everything was downloaded and installed. And it was a new installation - I hadn't to remove an older version and make backups first. I won't recommend someone to do this unless I have a rather clear idea that it will help.

Comment: @efpies: You shouldn't run updates if you have a deadline.

Comment: UlrikeFischer: I said it required little manual work. It will take some time for the computer, that is of course true. 

Also, updating Miktex days before a deadline is just too brave.

Comment: efpies: I'm glad you resolved the problem!

Comment: Reinstalling MikTeX is not enough. He should get a new computer. NOT.

Comment: Reinstalling Miktex didn't help in my case (Windows 7 64 bit). I think the Problem is not with the Latex packages, but with the MikTex packages. Curiously there is not problem with my second PC (Windows 8 Developer Preview 32 bit).

Answer (score 5):

I had to delete my *.aux file and there was a *.synctex(busy) file which I also deleted. Then I could compile again.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me on Windows 7:

1. Reboot.
2. Install all latest MiKTeX updates:

   [image: Screenshot of start menu with entry "Update"]
3. Reboot.
4. Refresh FNDB (file name database) using MikTeX Options:

   [image: Screenshot of start menu with entry "Settings"]
   [image: Screenshot of window "Options"]

   During this step, additional packages were installed.

The reboots were done because, after testing, there were issues with processes locking files.

Possibly related: On my system I got an error message about a missing QT5 DLL, which I solved by installing package: `miktex-qt5-bin`